# Delete a list of file/directory names

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line, command-line-interface

I have a list of file and directory names:

```
foo.js FOOBAR bar.json fubar/ .foo/ .baz
```

Is there a way to pass them to `find`, `grep` or something and delete all with one command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use `rm`?

```
rm -fr -- foo.js FOOBAR bar.json fubar/ .foo/ .baz
```

- `--` is optional if one of your file arguments starts with `-`.

If you want to recursively delete files with those filenames recursively, you can do this:

```
find path \( -name foo.js -o -name FOOBAR -o -name bar.json -o -name fubar -o -name .foo -o -name .baz \) -exec rm -fr -- '{}' \;
```

Similarly with `xargs`:

```
find path \( -name foo.js -o -name FOOBAR -o -name bar.json -o -name fubar -o -name .foo -o -name .baz \) -print0 | xargs -0 rm -fr --
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

`rm -rf foo.js FOOBAR bar.json fubar/ .foo/ .baz`.

`-r` option will remove those files recursively and `-f` option will remove those files forcefully.

If all the files are in same folder then `rm -rf *` will do the job!